# Fill 'NA's in data frame with information contained in one of the rows with a patient's ID using R

Tags: r

I have the following data frame in R:

```
ID  Information
1    Yes
1    NA
1    NA
1    Yes
2    No
2    NA
2    NA
3    NA
3    NA
3    Maybe
3    NA
```

I need to fill out the rows that contain NA's with whatever information is contained in one of the rows corresponding to that ID.
I would like to have this:

```
ID  Information
1   Yes
1   Yes
1   Yes
1   Yes
2   No
2   No
2   No
3   Maybe
3   Maybe
3   Maybe
3   Maybe
```

As far as I know, the information (ie Yes/No/Maybe) is not conflicting within an ID but it may be repeated.(Sorry about the ugly format- I am a newbie and may not post pictures).

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is using `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'ID', we assign (`:=`) 'Information' as the `unique` non-NA element.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(df1)[, Information:=unique(Information[!is.na(Information)]), by = ID]
df1
#     ID Information
#  1:  1         Yes
#  2:  1         Yes
#  3:  1         Yes
#  4:  1         Yes
#  5:  2          No
#  6:  2          No
#  7:  2          No
#  8:  3       Maybe
#  9:  3       Maybe
# 10:  3       Maybe
# 11:  3       Maybe
```

Or we can join the dataset with the unique rows of dataset after removing the 'NA' rows.  Here, I use the `devel` version of `data.table`

```
 setDT(unique(na.omit(df1)))[df1['ID'], on='ID']
```

Or we use `dplyr`, grouped by 'ID', we `arrange` the 'Information' so that 'NA' will be the last, create the 'Information' as the first value of 'Information'.

```
 library(dplyr)
 df1 %>%
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    arrange(Information) %>% 
    mutate(Information= first(Information))
```

Comment: another option would be using `na.locf` from `zoo` like this `setDT(d)[, Information:= na.locf(Information), by = ID]`

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar Looks like the `na.locf` worked for the example.  So, probably I was wrong.

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar  I think you need `transform` or `mutate` as `summarise` is just summarising the result to a single row or so.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option using `na.locf` with `ddply`

```
library(zoo)
library(plyr)

ddply(d, .(ID), mutate, Information = na.locf(Information))

#   ID Information
#1   1         Yes
#2   1         Yes
#3   1         Yes
#4   1         Yes
#5   2          No
#6   2          No
#7   2          No
#8   3       Maybe
#9   3       Maybe
#10  3       Maybe
#11  3       Maybe
```

Answer (score 2):

Or in base R:

```
uniqueCombns <- unique(dat[complete.cases(dat),])
merge(dat["ID"], uniqueCombns, by="ID", all.x=T)
```

where dat is your dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Since `DF$information` is a valid "factor" and there are no conflictions, you could, also, do (unless I'm ignoring something):

```
levels(DF$Information)[approxfun(DF$ID, DF$Information, method = "constant")(DF$ID)]
# [1] "Yes"   "Yes"   "Yes"   "Yes"   "No"    "No"    "No"    "Maybe" "Maybe" "Maybe" "Maybe"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is exactly one non-NA in each group we can simply omit the NAs and assign the remaining value to all the others doing this by group.  No packages are used:

```
transform(df,  Information = ave(Information, ID, FUN = na.omit))
```

giving:

```
   ID Information
1   1         Yes
2   1         Yes
3   1         Yes
4   1         Yes
5   2          No
6   2          No
7   2          No
8   3       Maybe
9   3       Maybe
10  3       Maybe
11  3       Maybe
```

If there can be more than one non-NA in each group but they are all the same then replace `na.omit` with `function(x) na.omit(x)[1]` .

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the NA values were not always first in the group (you can see it at ID 3). Thank you anyway!

Comment: OK.  In that case I have changed the answer.